# a file-base FoxPro Database in asp.net issues

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, foxpro, app-data

I have a collection of data stored in a FoxPro database in my local system . I want to use this data in my website . now I don't know what is the best way to use it .

1- to place the database itself in app_data and use VFP Oledb provider to extract data from ? 
2- Or to use it as a linked server with my current sql server ?
3- or create a page that uploads VFP database then export it's records to a sql server database with the same schema ?

I can't answer these questions because : 
I don't know how secure and scalable is a database placed in app_data /
is FoxPro database a good choice as a website backend data store / 
exporting data from VPF to Sql database through code is not error proof ( I'm not sure if I lose records and FKs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how often the data change? Do you need it real time? If yes, give it a try with linked servers:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199131

If you can have a X hours\minutes delay (that will depend on the size of your data), how about building SSIS packages to run on a regular basis to get the data from FoxPro and insert into a SQl Server database?

Comment: thank you . data is planned to be updated once a month . how does SSIS work ? it's automated or should be lunched each time ? is SSIS accessible through asp.net code ?

Comment: that you would be good to use SSIS. basically you will build a package that reads data from your source and inserts into your destination (foxpro -> SQl Server). You dont need asp.net code, you can schedule your package to be run monthly using SQl Server jobs

Comment: good tool , but I still want to know can I control SSIS Package through code or not ? for example to build an app to run it when I need ( maybe earlier than next month )?

Comment: yes, you execute a package from code. but this is the thing you usually do using SQL Server jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Visual FoxPro also has an upsizing wizard that will do the heavy lifting of converting your Visual Foxpro database to SQL Server including the table structures and data.

Comment: If you want to use the Upsizing Wizard, make sure to use the Sedna version, available at http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna&referringTitle=Home.